# Is there a simple way for IE7 to render page as it was IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Here's the site that renders well in IE5.5, IE6 and IE8+, but not IE7.

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html .

There is a lot of job done there (over 9000 hacks).  Is there a way for IE7 to render it in IE6 mode?

---

**UPDATE**: I know the source of the problem. It's here:

```
html>body tbody {
    ...
    height: 262px;
    ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE2**: I've read [this](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks) and fixed it. WAAHOOO, i'm a [css guru](http://www.flickr.com/photos/atzu/4365152223/lightbox/)!!!

Change previous code to this:

```
html>/**/body tbody {
    ...
    height: 262px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the *compatibility* setting was introduced in IE8. So I think you may be out of luck. But we'll see.

Comment: "(over 9000 hacks)" - death by 9000 cuts?

Comment: I would suggest if you have 9000 hacks, you're probably doing things the hard way.

Comment: That's the only CSS-only example that works in ie6

Comment: @atzu You're great photographer!

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments can't be a solution. They don't work in IE7. You should use CSS hacks instead. You can find a list of reliable hacks here: http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks

**IE 6 and below**

```
* html {}
```

**IE 7 and below**

```
*:first-child+html {} * html {}
```

**IE 7 only**

```
*:first-child+html {}
```

**IE 8 only**

```
 .ie8only { color /*\**/: #fff\9 }
```

(I would dream of some cleaner solution, but can't get an idea...)